# Intuition on Axiom of Completeness

Tags: real-analysis, intuition, axioms, visualization

> ♪ (J. Stewart. Calculus 6th ed. pp 682) Axiom of Completeness = AoC
>   = A nonempty set of real numbers that has an upper bound has a least upper bound.
>   AoC is an expression of the fact that there is no gap or hole in the real number line.

**1.** Intuition please on the Axiom of Completeness? How does AoC warrant 'no gap or hole'?

**2.** (http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=648536) Person micromass says this expression is 'rubbish' and then 'good intuition'? I'm nonplussed. What's flawed and immaculate?

[image]

> ♪ pp 4 of 7 (http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~klages/mth4100/week1.pdf)
>   In summary, the real numbers R are complete in the sense that they correspond to all points
>   on the real line, i.e., there are no “holes” or “gaps”, whereas the rationals have ”holes”
>   (namely the irrationals).
>
> ♪  pp 1 of 8 (ttp://www.nku.edu/~longa/classes/2011fall/mat420/days/highlights/highlights1.3.pdf)
>
> There are “holes” in the set of rational numbers – interesting numbers that aren’t
>   rational. This completeness axiom merely asserts that all the holes are filled in for the
>   real numbers (with the additional of the irrational numbers).

Comment: We could repeat the discussions you quoted. It depends on what having a hole means. The example of $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ shows how careful one has to be with it. What completeness gives us is that every sequence that *should* convergre *does* converge. Whatever "should" means here ... (heck, this is about intuition)

Comment: I think looking at the proofs of the intermediate and extreme value theorems should give you a better intuition for the meaning of completeness (and what is it that the reals have but the rationals don't). My favourite approach is the chapter "Three Hard Theorems" on Spivak's Calculus.